# Archive of iOS / android app icons?

Tags: icons, android, iphone, branding

In creating an iOS app icons, it'd be great to see if I'm getting too close to anything that is already out there... but is there any good way to check?  I haven't come across any archives out there of mobile device app icons.

I think of an amazing resource like this ( http://bookcoverarchive.com/ ) for book covers, and wonder why I don't know about the iphone icon equivalent.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

UPD: http://iosicongallery.com

Here is a small collection of apps icons that hopefully will help you:
http://www.iosinspires.me/category/appicons/

Also try to search Dribbble:
http://dribbble.com/search?page=2&q=app+icon

Answer (score 1):

[IconFinder](http://www.iconfinder.com/) has some really nice icons, but they are not categorized by types you are looking for (mobile, iOS).

Some related icons might be found be searching for [Applications](http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=application) and [Apple](http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=apple).

Comment: Thanks Jawa - I've often used iconFinder to see what's out there for "gears" or "envelope" for example... but I'm actually not talking about in-app-icons.  I should have been more clear.  I'm talking about the actual app's icon - as in the big 512px x 512px (and smaller sized) icon that appears in the app store and the device's home screen.  I'm not a huge fan of searching using the app store itself, and it would be great to know if the app icon I'm working on is dangerously close to something else out there.  An indexed/tagged archive of approved apps / icons is really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well this would work for icons but google image search now has a way to upload an image and find visually-similar images. After the initial search you can add keywords to the uploaded image data to narrow results.

Just click on the icon in the image search field to upload an image: https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi

I used this to look for larger versions of an image I found recently and it worked great. For other uses, it not always is great. It seems to look for image with similar color distribution. It's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS apps, you could look through the Popular Apps section on http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8 for your specific category.